# Brackets in a calculator for java

Tags: java, arraylist, calculator, multiplication

I am trying to implement a calculator that works just like the normal calculators, I managed to block out many inputs from keyboard to prevent unnecessary characters, Then i managed to analyze the textfield content and put the content in an arraylist. The array list contains operators including brackets and put in the array list as well. Now I want to be able to take the brackets and perform multiplication for them or perform the operator that comes before it. My code for the bracket analyzer is as below

```
private void BracketSolver(int opnBracketPosition, ArrayList Analyzed)
{Boolean _closed=true;
    for (int i=opnBracketPosition;i<Analyzed.size();i++)//check all array element
    {
        if (Analyzed.get(i).equals("("))//if its an open bracket
        {
             _closed = false;//a bracket opened
             if(Analyzed.get(i+1).equals("-")){//if a minus after the bracket, then turn the number after the minus to a negative and delete the minus
             Analyzed.set(i+2,String.valueOf((-1)*Double.parseDouble(Analyzed.get(i+2).toString())));
             Analyzed.remove(i+1);}
            for (int j=i+1;j<Analyzed.size();j++){//check all element after the open bracket
                if(Analyzed.get(j).equals("("))
                {

                    BracketSolver(j, Analyzed);i=0;
                }//if we meet another open bracket, then restart the function from there
                else if(Analyzed.get(j).equals(")"))//but if its a closing
                {
                    _closed = true;//it has been closed
                    if(i!=0){//make sure is not zero to prevent error of i-1=-1
                   if((Analyzed.get(i-1).equals("+"))||(Analyzed.get(i-1).equals("-"))
                            ||(Analyzed.get(i-1).equals("x"))||(Analyzed.get(i-1).equals("^"))
                            ||(Analyzed.get(i-1).equals("÷"))||(Analyzed.get(i-1).equals("√"))) {
                       //if an operator is before the bracket then just delete the brackets and calculate
                    Analyzed.remove(j);Analyzed.remove(i);//remove the brackets
                    Calculator_Basic(Analyzed, i, j-1);//solve for all after the open bracket n before the close     
                }
                    else{Analyzed.remove(j);Analyzed.set(i,String.valueOf('x'));
                    //remove the close bracket but change the open bracket to multiply
                    Calculator_Basic(Analyzed, i+1, j-1);//solve for all after the open bracket n before the close
                }
                }else{    Analyzed.remove(j);Analyzed.remove(i);//remove the brackets
                    Calculator_Basic(Analyzed, i, j-1);//solve for all after the open bracket n before the close
                }//i=0;//restart
                }
           }
        }
    }  if(!_closed)//if it has ended and still no close
                 {throw new IllegalArgumentException("Syntax Error: Bracket Not Closed");
                 }
}
```

the function calculator_Basic is another function that takes an arraylist and a start and end integer and calculates everything in between. It already works fine but if you need it to help me out i can paste it as well, though it is very plenty and rough. Now my problem is this code cannot perform on something like (5)(8). I do not know why. I know my code is plenty and might be uneasy to understand.
The next set of code is what I used in storing the text field into an array list

```
private static ArrayList<String> AnalyzedContent;
private void Analyzer()//function that analyzes the user input char by char and takes the numbers
{
    AnalyzedContent = new ArrayList();//to store everything
   char[] operators = {'+','-','x','÷','^','√','(',')'};//array holding all operators
   String set = "";//string to hold the numbers
    for (int i=0;i<Display.getText().length();i++)//for all chars in display
    {//if its an operator
if((Display.getText().charAt(i)==operators[0])||(Display.getText().charAt(i)==operators[1])||(Display.getText().charAt(i)==operators[2])
        ||(Display.getText().charAt(i)==operators[3])||(Display.getText().charAt(i)==operators[4])||(Display.getText().charAt(i)==operators[5])
        ||(Display.getText().charAt(i)==operators[6])||(Display.getText().charAt(i)==operators[7]))
                {
                if (!set.equals(""))AnalyzedContent.add(set);//check if set is not empty then store its content
                    set = "";//reset the set
                    for (int j = 0; j<operators.length;j++){//check which operator it is and store
                        if (Display.getText().charAt(i)==operators[j])
                        {
                            if((i==0)&&(j!=6))throw new ArithmeticException("Syntax Error::Cannot Begin with Operator");
                        //if it is start of the display and operator is not open bracket then throw error
                            AnalyzedContent.add(operators[j] + "");
                        }}
                     //j=operators.length;//leave the loop when something is found
                }
                else//else if its a number append to set which might already contain numbers not separated by an operator
                {
                   set = set + Display.getText().charAt(i);//append the number to previous
                }
        }if (!set.equals(""))AnalyzedContent.add(set);//check if set is not empty then store its content
```

thanks in advance anyone
    Again, My if statement for the operators using || is very rough, I am guessing there is a neater way to do it, if someone could help me there too.

Comment: The usual approach for this kind of problem is to use a grammar (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154628/antlr-grammar-issue-calculator-language) , but of course, trying to solve this problem the way you're doing is a good step in order to understand the problem. By the way, what result do you expect from "(5)(8)"?

Comment: @Leo I expect it to result in 5x8 that is to 40. I have tried problems like (5x8), (5x8(2)), and many others, they all work. My only problem is the format I mentioned(5)(8). Thanks for the suggestion although I do not know how to use grammers in java, i would check to see.

Comment: Grammar is the way to go in this case, but most grammars won't consider (5)(8) = 5 x 8, because there's no operation token (in this case, it's an implicit one) so you may need some hack to make it work this way.